# Keyboard setup for Eclipse on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I've finished my first course in java at college and want to practice on my own computer.

However, after downloading eclipse and being able to write very simple programs, I hit a snag when I tried to write programs which take user input using e.g:

```java
Keyboard.in.readInteger();
```

Because "`Keyboard cannot be resolved`".

I have used this successfully on lab computers, but how do I get it to accept my keyboard inputs?

Thank you
B

Comment: Sounds like the Keyboard class was provided by your classroom environment?  Google 'java keyboard input' for a bunch of samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classic examples of reading input from the keyboard don't involve a Keyboard class (like the [Simple input from the keyboard](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0053.html) from the [Real's HowTo](http://www.rgagnon.com/howto.html)).

So your "`Keyboard`" class is likely to be a custom one, as illustrated by this [cs1.Keyboard](http://duke.csc.villanova.edu/jss/downloads/Keyboard.java) file (which at least don't give you direct public access to the `InputStreamReader` ;) ).